# How to automatically close fancybox 4 popup after x seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fancybox

I have a web page page.html with this fancybox4 link

```
<a href="link.html" data-fancybox data-type="iframe" data-width="80%" data-height="25%" >
```

I would close automatically fancybox iframe link.html after 3 seconds.

I tried variuos solutions found in stackexchange but nothing worked (all solutions are referred to fancybox2 or older version).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation - https://fancyapps.com/docs/ui/fancybox/api - you can close Fancybox using `Fancybox.close();` - so, all you have to do is to figure out how to execute it after some timeout

Comment: I tried it , it does not work.

Comment: Since you did not provide a link to working demo where your issue could be inspected, it is not possible to help you.